# Why does Scripture imply Jesus had siblings if Mary was "ever virgin" per Catholic belief?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus

If Mary remained "ever virgin", even after the birth of Jesus, then why does Scripture refer to in Mark 6:3, Matthew 13:55, John 7:3, Acts 1:13 and 1 Corinthians 9:5 which mention "James the Just", Joses, Simon and Jude as brothers of Jesus? And why does Matthew 13:56 make reference to Jesus' sisters? Are these errors in Scripture? Dan M. St. Louis,MO

Comment: Two possibilities - one being that there was a mistranslation or that they were children from a previous marriage with Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is that the Greek word *adelphos* can be translated as "brother", but can also mean "cousin" or having the same national origin.

> a brother, whether born of the same two parents or only of the same father or mother
> having the same national ancestor, belonging to the same people, or countryman
> any fellow or man
> a fellow believer, united to another by the bond of affection
> an associate in employment or office
> brethren in Christ
> his brothers by blood
> all men
> apostles
> Christians, as those who are exalted to the same heavenly place
> [-outline-](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g80/kjv/tr/0-1/)

Catholics understand the word to mean cousins (i.e., having different parents), while members of the Orthodox church understand it to mean "step-brothers," with Joseph having children prior to marrying Mary.  Thayer (using Strong) believes the word means neither cousins nor step-brothers but simply brothers (having the same mother but different fathers).

> STRONGS NT 80: ἀδελφός
> ἀδελφός, -οῦ, ὁ (from α copulative and δελφύς, from the same womb; cf. ἀγάστωρ) [from Homer down];

1. a brother (whether born of the same two parents, or only of the same father or the same mother): Matthew 1:2; Matthew 4:18, and often. That 'the brethren of Jesus,' Matthew 12:46, 47 [but WH only in marginal reading]; Matthew 13:55f; Mark 6:3 (in the last two passages also sisters); Luke 8:19; John 2:12; John 7:3; Acts 1:14; Galatians 1:19; 1 Corinthians 9:5, are neither sons of Joseph by a wife married before Mary (which is the account in the Apocryphal Gospels [cf. Thilo, Cod. Apocr. N. T. i. 362f]), nor cousins, the children of Alphæus or Cleophas [i. e. Clopas]
   -ibid-

Vine understands it this way:

> Brother, Brethren, Brotherhood, Brotherly:
> denotes "a brother, or near kinsman;" in the plural, "a community based on identity of origin or life." It is used of:
> (1) male children of the same parents, Matt 1:2; 14:3;
> (2) male descendants of the same parents, Act 7:23, 26; Hbr 7:5;
> (3) male children of the same mother, Mat 13:55; 1Cr 9:5; Gal 1:19;
> (4) people of the same nationality, Act 3:17, 22; Rom 9:3. With "men" (aner, "male"), prefixed, it is used in addresses only, Act 2:29, 37, etc.;
> (5) any man, a neighbor, Luk 10:29; Mat 5:22; 7:3;
> (6) persons united by a common interest, Mat 5:47;
> (7) persons united by a common calling, Rev 22:9;
> (8) mankind, Mat 25:40; Hbr 2:17;
> (9) the disciples, and so, by implication, all believers, Mat 28:10; Jhn 20:17;
> (10) believers, apart from sex, Mat 23:8; Act 1:15; Rom 1:13; 1Th 1:4; Rev 19:10 (the word "sisters" is used of believers, only in 1Ti 5:2);
> (11) believers, with aner, "male," prefixed, and with "or sister" added, 1Cr 7:14 (RV), 15; Jam 2:15, male as distinct from female, Act 1:16; 15:7, 13, but not Act 6:3. *
> [* From Notes on Thessalonians, by Hogg and Vine, p. 32.]
> Notes:
> (1) Associated words are adelphotes, primarily, "a brotherly relation," and so, the community possessed of this relation, "a brotherhood," 1Pe 2:17 (see 5:9, marg.); philadelphos, (phileo, "to love," and adelphos), "fond of one's brethren," 1Pe 3:8; "loving as brethren," RV; philadelphia, "brotherly love," Rom 12:10; 1Th 4:9; Hbr 13:1; "love of the brethren," 1Pe 1:22; 2Pe 1:7, RV; pseudadelphos, "false brethren," 2Cr 11:26; Gal 2:4.
> (2) In Luk 6:16; Act 1:13, the RV has "son," for AV, "brother."
> -ibid-

So, many believe the word *adelphos* may mean not only uterine siblings, but also relatives having the same nationality.

To answer the last question, there may be a contradiction between Catholicism's Tradition and Scripture, but that is not the same as saying the Bible contradicts itself.